# python and windows double backslash

Tags: python

I got a program running on my local machine which uses some files. I create the reference to the files by using: `os.path.join( tempfile.gettempdir(), 'filename.txt' )`

After that I'm running a program which accepts some parameters `--log-file filepath` where filepath is one of the files I just explained above.

On my machine python creates backslashes for the paths but not double backslashes and the program complains because it's considered an escape character and should be a double backslash.

Is there any standard way of making sure that I get a working path with double backslashes in python? I could use regex but I would prefer something similar to what `os.` provides. Maybe I'm missing something.

I'm calling the program using `subprocess.Popen`:

`self._proc = subprocess.Popen( command.split( ' ' ) )`

where `command` is something like `pcix.exe --log-file file_path`

Also, running a test on my console shows that my python does not produce double backslash for paths:

```
>>> print os.path.join(tempfile.gettempdir(), "test.txt")
c:\users\manilo~1\appdata\local\temp\test.txt
```

Leaving out the print command produces the same path:

```
>>> os.path.join(tempfile.gettempdir(), "test.txt")
c:\users\manilo~1\appdata\local\temp\test.txt
```

Any idea why?

P.S. The platform i'm running is `CPython`

Comment: Please show how you're calling the second program.

Comment: Windows doesn't use double backslashes; Python string literals do. What you're printing isn't a string literal; it should be a perfectly reasonable Windows path. Leave off the `print` and you'll see it in string literal form with double backslashes.

Comment: What's the actual error you're seeing?

Comment: I'm getting this `Options warning: Bad backslash ('\') usage. Remember
that backslashes are treated as shell-escapes and if you need to pass
backslash characters as part of a Windows filename, you should use double backslashes`

Comment: leaving out the `print` thing still outputs single backslash.

Comment: What platform, Cygwin or something?

Comment: Would os.path.normpath help in this case?

Comment: I just downloaded python from their website. I work all the time on linux and only downloaded windows 7 to try this thing out since I'm gonna release it to my clients. The one complaining is the program executed and not python itself. The whole thing works on my computer but other computer with same windows 7 installed complains of this thing and the program does not run at all. `os.path.normpath` produces the same thing.

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
print os.path.join(tempfile.gettempdir(), "test.txt").replace('\\\\','\\\\\\\\')
```